BiomartException: Query ERROR for existing dataset in BioMart
I am trying to fetch protein sequences for a list of gene IDs using from BioMart API using the Python code:
def fetch_protein_sequences(gene_ids):
    dataset = Dataset(name='taestivum_eg_gene', host='http://plants.ensembl.org')
    # Fetch protein sequences
    response = dataset.query(
        attributes=[
            'ensembl_gene_id', 
            'peptide'
        ],
        filters={'gene_id': gene_ids}
    )
    return response

# Read gene IDs from file
with open('gene_ids.txt') as f:
    gene_ids = [line.strip() for line in f]

# Fetch protein sequences
protein_sequences = fetch_protein_sequences(gene_ids)

but keep enoutering
BiomartException: Query ERROR: caught BioMart::Exception::Usage: WITHIN Virtual Schema : default, Dataset taestivum_eg_gene NOT FOUND

Verified dateset and attributes using:
server = Server(host='http://plants.ensembl.org')
for dataset in server.marts['plants_mart'].datasets:
    print(dataset)

Could someone please help me understand why I am seeing this error?
Thank you in advance!
